# Recreating a component when data changes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Ok so there seems to be a lot of answers to this question but I haven't been able to comprehend what I should do.

I currently have a child component that is being created when someone clicks a play button from another child component. This is happening through a service which shares the data with my parent and then the parent passes the data and creates my child audio-player component. The problem I'm having is if the user navigates to another page and clicks to play the audio on that page the old audio still persists and the new audio doesn't start.

Is there a lifecycle hook or a method I could use to destroy my old audio component and create a new audio onclick?

Info Box - Where the initial activation happens when play button is clicked.

```
export class InfoBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  activateAudioPlayer(session) {
    this.newAudioService.newAudio(session)
  }
}
```

New Audio Service

```
export class NewAudioService {
  newActiveAudioSource: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  newAudio(session) {
    this.newActiveAudioSource.next(session);
  }

  newActiveAudio$ = this.newActiveAudioSource.asObservable();
}
```

Frontend Component - Parent Component of Info Box and Audio Player

```
@Component({ 
   template: `<audio-player *ngIf='newActiveAudio' [newActiveAudio]='newActiveAudio'></audio-player>`,
})

export class FrontendComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.newAudioService.newActiveAudio$.subscribe(
      newActiveAudio => {
        this.newActiveAudio = newActiveAudio;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: The `InfoBoxComponent` is what gets created and then destroyed multiple times and that should also destroy the audio element?

Comment: The InfoBoxComponent is created onInit of my frontendComponent, the audioplayerComponent is created when a button from the infoBoxComponent is clicked. I do this so the user can navigate my site and still have the audio playing until they find another selection they want to play. The problem is once the audioPlayerComponent is initialized I need a way to destroy it and recreate it with different data. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original question.

Comment: Just curious if this works: `this.sub = this.newAudioService.newActiveAudio$.subscribe(
      newActiveAudio => {
        this.newActiveAudio = null;
        this.newActiveAudio = newActiveAudio;
      });`
However, I would say, that you should use `OnChange` inside of `audio-player` and unload (stop/pause/destroy) old audio object, then load new one.

Comment: OnChange works too! The only issue I'm having now is because the audio element is created within the js it continues to play when the other one is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible way could be setting `this.newActiveAudio = false` then letting Angular update the view with `setTimeout()` and then set the new value for `newActiveAudio`:

```
this.sub = this.newAudioService.newActiveAudio$.subscribe(newActiveAudio => {
    this.newActiveAudio = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.newActiveAudio = newActiveAudio;
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool this works! The only issue it brings is that the old audio continues to play but I think this is because I'm adding the audio file dynamically. I'm sure I can kill the audio element onInit of the audioplayer though.

Comment: I'm not sure just removing the element from DOM will stop it from playing though...

Answer (score 14):

Here is a small directive that recreates view when `key` value changes:

```
import {
  Directive,
  EmbeddedViewRef,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[wRecreateViewKey]'
})
export class RecreateViewDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('wRecreateViewKey') key: any;

  viewRef: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.key) {
      if (this.viewRef) {
        this.destroyView();
      }

      this.createView();
    }
  }

  private createView() {
    this.viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

  private destroyView() {
    this.viewRef.destroy();
    this.viewRef = null;
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```html
<!-- `some-component` will be destroyed and recreated every time `value` changes. -->

<some-component *wRecreateViewKey="value"></some-component>

<!-- Can also be used on regular DOM elements or container -->
<div *wRecreateViewKey="value"></div>
<ng-container *wRecreateViewKey="value"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this should be the accepted answer! The most elegant and reusable solution, without any setTimeouts.

Comment: Completly aggree! This is a smart and clean solution! Thank you very much for sharing it!

Comment: It works! With one correction though:  if(changes['key'])

Answer (score 7):

Found a little hack for this. Put your element in an one element array and create ngFor with trackBy

```
 <component *ngFor="let o of [object]; trackBy: trackByObjectProperty">
        </component>
```

Comment: If the signal `object` is immutable, you don't need the `trackBy` parameter, because `ngFor` tracks by comparing instances by default. E.g. you could use `let o of [count]`, where `count` is something you increment each time the component needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

After setting newAudioService to null, ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() should be used to force a screen update.
This destroys the component.
We then reconfigure newActiveAudio and regenerate the component.

**html**

```
<audio-player *ngIf='newActiveAudio' [newActiveAudio]='newActiveAudio'></audio-player>
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.newAudioService.newActiveAudio$.subscribe(
        newActiveAudio => {
            this.newActiveAudio = null;
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            this.newActiveAudio = newActiveAudio;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Please consider to improve your answer with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71693784/edit) to add further details, such as solution explanation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).